# Can you perform an action based on a seperate window in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page of search results, and clicking one opens a new window where they edit the information about it. Once they finish, they currently have to hit "search" again to refresh the results to ensure it saved correctly (it refreshes the search results and reflects the new status).

Is there any way to trigger the page to automatically refresh (ie. automatically click the search button) based on the popup window closing or through some other means?

Comment: Why do you use a popup to edit the item? Can't you use a dataview or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, yep it's really nasty but such is a life of editing nasty legacy code... No time to rewrite it all yet. It's like in firefly when the captain refuses to buy replacement parts for the ship's engine despite the fact it's totally falling apart... "as long as it works or you can get it working" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I echo the sentiments to do this without popup windows, but if you really need to...

I would do this with an update panel wrapped around the results and some javascript added to your save button on the popup page.

On your **popup page**, I guess you have a button to save your work, something like:

```
<asp:button id="btn_save" runat="server" OnClick="Save" Text="save" />
```

on the codebehind:

```
protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // save code ...
   // bla bla

   // Add this
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "save", "<script language='javascript'>updateResults();</script>
}
```

On the **results** page add this

```
<script language="javascript">
function updateResults()
{
  __doPostBack('updatePanel_results','');
}
</script>
```

and wrap your results control in an update panel (in this example called updatePanel_results).  In your page_load, you'll probably need to code to call your refresh resutls method.

Comment: You're welcome.  Let me know if you run into trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really avoid having the application flow spanning two windows if possible.  Why not impliment some kind of modal dialogue when the user clicks an edit link?

Check out jQuery's modal form implimentation to see what I mean:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 0):

Opening window does not look like the ideal solution here.

In the new window you have access to parent window in javascript. You can use it to fire refresh/or some other function in mail window.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to trigger the page
>   to automatically refresh (ie.
>   automatically click the search button)
>   based on the popup window closing or
>   through some other means?

You can register a JavaScript event handler for the OnUnload event.  However, in my experience it's not reliable (browser-to-browser inconsistencies, etc).

Have you considered using Ajax to keep the search results on the same page as the original window?  Or maybe a small Silverlight control?